# Lead insert with owner as Spam using Web-to-Lead

Tags: leads

I am posting lead to salesforce using Web-to-Lead. Lead created successfully but displaying lead owner as spam.

Please suggest.

Comment: please explain .. the question is not clear ..

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce, by default, assigns leads to the creator of your organization. At some point, one or your current or prior administrators customized the setting to send leads elsewhere. There are four possible places you may need to check.

Setup > Customize > Leads > Web to Lead

Here, you'll find settings to set a default owner, and turn the service on of off.

Setup > Customize > Leads > Assignment Rules

The active rule may have a rule entry to send leads to the a Spam queue (admin defined).

Setup > Create > Workflow and Approvals > Workflow Rules

Check for lead workflow rules that are active to see if any cause this assignment.

Setup > Customize > Leads > Triggers

A specially crafted trigger could assign lead ownership.

You could also open a case with Support, and they would probably be nice enough to help you track down why this happens.